# Is the work of Pop Artists considered graphic design?

Tags: art

Roy Lichtenstein for example, is his work considered a piece of Graphic Design?

Comment: There is a thin line between art and everything else a human could be doing. But basically graphic design is about solving a problem via visual means. Usually its a communication problem of some kind. But the line isnt entirely clear, where something starts and where it ends is highly subjective. For example i know of a graphic design professor who is adamant that all package design is graphic design. Though im pretty sure ammo crates are packages and not usually considered graphic design. In fact there are lots of packages that arent graphic design related.

Comment: Point is that it depends on whose definition and authority you follow. Poster making is certainly graphic design, but are all posters graphic design?

Comment: I had once read that if you're creating something for someone else, you're a designer. If you're creating for yourself, you're an artist. I've also many craftsmen in my day - ie, auto mechanics, bookbinders, even pressmen, who I consider artists because the finished job was more important to them than anyone else. :)

Comment: I think this amounts to exclusively *opinion*.

Answer (score 2):

Even though yes indeed, influenced by commercial design, RL's art is very clearly labeled as 'pop art', being collected, sold and re-sold as art, at art galleries and art auctions.

More so there are a significant number of artists taking influence from the industrial or commercial: that's doesn't mean they are welders, car mechanics or pharmacists, they just take that reality and use it to create unique pieces of art.